# Handling overlapping asynchronous POST requests

Tags: post, design-patterns

We have implemented [How to Use POST for Asynchronous Tasks](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/restful-web-services/9780596809140/ch01s10.html) in our project for long running tasks.

My question is how we can handle the case wherein we have multiple POST requests issued back-to-back from the same client. In this case, only the last POST request is what the client really is interested in. When a POST triggers a background thread, a subsequent POST also tries to trigger another background thread.

This effectively means that apart from the last POST request, the others result in wasteful computation

Are there any design patterns to address this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a commonly accepted pattern for this situation.

There are at least 2 situations where the duplicate POST can arise:

1. The client re-transmits the original POST for whatever reason ( such as it missed the response).
2. The user re-transmits either the original POST (intentionally or not) or he issues a new POST intended to replace the earlier versions.

It's best to deal with the problem at the server side.

One solution is to add a unique identifier (such as a GUID or a natural key) to each POST, and then have the server check if a request with that identifier already exists or not.  Your server will need to save state somewhere while an existing POST is being processed (cookie, SESSION, local file, database are options) .

Note if you use a GUID you have to be sure that the client does not create a new GUID for re-transmits of the same request. You can avoid this problem by using a natural key instead of a GUID generator. The generation of the natural key should be repeatable and (reasonably) unique.